# Turn off Incredible Bottom Lights

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, buttons, backlight

Droid Incredible has 4 buttons below the screen that are very bright at night. I'd like to turn these off when I'm reading from the screen. Is there any way to do this without rooting the phone?

Answer (score 1):

[From what I've read](http://androidforums.com/incredible-support-troubleshooting/73519-turning-off-light-4-lower-buttons.html), this is not possible without a rooted phone.  Other than that, you can you only control the lights' on/off state by how much ambient light is hitting the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there must be some way to do this because FBreader turns then off whether there is high or low lighting.

http://www.appbrain.com/app/fbreader/org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android

Even a note about this in the FBreader releases:

FBReaderJ 0.7.12/13 is released (October 28, 2010).
Changes:
    * Keys backlight has been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called Screen Filter which allows dimming of the screen, as well as disabling the bottom button lights. However, as my phone is rooted, I am not entirely sure if the button light disabling works on a non-rooted incredible. The app is free though, so it is worth a try.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.haxor&hl=en